# Как внедрить изменения с предыдущей истории?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Есть одна ветка c условно 10-ю commits.
После переключения (`git checkout` ...)
на 8-й из этих 10-ти (в плане очереди истории) `commit` были реализованы изменения.
Далее требуется реализовать `commit` и `push`(на `Github`).

Вопрос:
Как это корректно реализовать, если после попытки сделать в текущей истории `commit` и `push` я получаю следующий результат:

```
Mike_Kharkov@DESKTOP-O1H079M MINGW64 /e/Progi3/trading_strategy_tester ((b5fcc2c...))
$ git commit -m 'reset code for update new architecture'
[detached HEAD d966582] reset code for update new architecture
 16 files changed, 495 insertions(+), 1458 deletions(-)
 rewrite src/components/chartApp/chartContentApp/index.vue (84%)
 rewrite src/components/chartApp/chartContentApp/priceApp/index.vue (75%)
 rewrite src/components/chartApp/dateApp/dateElements/index.vue (78%)
 rewrite src/components/chartApp/dateApp/index.vue (74%)
 rewrite src/components/chartApp/priceVolumeWrap/priceWrap/index.vue (79%)
 rewrite src/components/chartApp/priceVolumeWrap/priceWrap/priceElements/index.vue (76%)
 rewrite src/components/chartApp/priceVolumeWrap/volumeWrap/index.vue (74%)
 rewrite src/components/chartApp/priceVolumeWrap/volumeWrap/volumeElements/index.vue (75%)
 rewrite src/components/chartApp/topChartMenuApp/index.vue (72%)
 rewrite src/store/index.js (98%)

Mike_Kharkov@DESKTOP-O1H079M MINGW64 /e/Progi3/trading_strategy_tester ((d966582...))
$ git status
HEAD detached from b5fcc2c
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Mike_Kharkov@DESKTOP-O1H079M MINGW64 /e/Progi3/trading_strategy_tester ((d966582...))
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

P.S. На `Github` не наблюдается никаких изменений после данных телодвижений.
Предполагаю, что в данном случается требуется каким то образом вернуться(переключиться в состояние) к последнему коммиту и во время этого возврата будет возможность привнести эти изменения уже в него - если это так то как это реализовать?

Comment: Непонятно, что тут хочется получить в итоге. Если надо, чтобы изменения в итоге появились в истории так, как будто они были сделаны после 8 коммита, но до 9, то надо сделать rebase коммитов 9 10 с 8 на новый. А уже затем пушать. При этом на стороне гитхаба надо убедиться, что изменение истории коммитов для этой ветки разрешено.

Comment: в идеале хотелось бы так что бы текущие изменения в 8-м коммите стали что то типа 11-м коммитом в этой же ветке и затем пушем - это реально?
(с сохранением всех предыдущих 10-ти коммитов)

Comment: Тогда эти изменения надо было добавлять, когда текущим был 10 коммит. По сути это был бы самый обычный коммит с изменениями

Comment: Так не получается по сколько в 10-м коммите слишком много надо переделывать в отличии от 8-го

Comment: ¿Т.е. в результате вы хотите откатить состояние некоторых файлов, к состоянию, как было в 8 коммите и затем еще внести правки?

Comment: Не совсем. Изначально был 8-й коммит(откат к нему с 10-го)
Далее сделаны новые изменения. Теперь стоит задача перенести все это хотя бы в 10-й коммит.
В  идеале вообще вынести в отдельный 11-й коммит